# Understanding Manipulator Dynamics for 3-DOF Robot

Tags: robotic-arm, control, kinematics, matlab, dynamics

I have this robot arm for a project I am tasked with. I need to compute the Newton-Euler and Lagrange Euler formulation for the arm. Then I should implement it on MATLAB.

I would appreciate some resources from where to start.

[image]